# How to position <div .right> above <div .left> when window is minimized, if <div .right> is to the right of <div .left> when window is large

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen this before but can't find out how to do it myself.

Essentially, we have text on the left, and an image floated on the right.

We'd like the image to appear above the text when the window is minimized, rather than below it as is normally the case.

This is how I could solve it. Any ideas of how to do this better?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .left{
            width:60%;
            position:absolute;
            padding:0px 30px;

        }

        .right{
            width:250px;
            height:250px;
            background-color:red;
            float:right;
            margin:0px 30px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            .left{
                width:90%;
                top:275px;

            }

            .right{
                float:none;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        }

    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<p class="left">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
<div class="right">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4aerjgd6/

P.S. Why is it that in this example, when the window is minimized pretty small, a horizontal scroll bar appears - is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks,
W

Comment: Yes plenty of people know how to achieve this and can help you. Please post the code for what you've tried so far and give us more to work from.

Comment: Use a media query to detect the device width, and change the CSS properties of the img tag (e.g. float: left;) when the device width is smaller than whatever you consider "minimized"

Comment: @TechnicCoder2000 fwiw your link is broken.  Should be http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TimTroiano Thanks. I've upadated the post - any way to take it off hold?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use a **media query** to detect the device width, and change the CSS properties of the img tag if the content is smaller than a certain value (whatever you consider "minimized")

2) In your case, change the `float property` on the `img` element to **float: left;**

For example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
     float: left;
  }
}
```